# Directive for a dynamic click function for items in a list... almost there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a list that I that depending on certain situations need to have different function called when I click on an item.

I made a directive that render the list template. It's on that directive that I would like to specify the function called when clicking an item.

```
controller..
  $scope.dataArray = dataFromService;
  $scope.showDetailsInModal = function(item) {
    // item is always undefined here :(
  }

<div my-list="dataArray" on-item-click="showDetailsInModal()"></div>

directive...
  scope: {
    data: '=myList',
    onItemClick: '&',
  },
  templateUrl: template.html
```

template.html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data"
      ng-click="onItemClick(item)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The function gets called (yeah) but the item passed in parameter is undefined when used in that function.. soooo.. I don't know why

Thanks for your help, has always!

Comment: show definition of `showDetailsInModal` ...also try passing it as reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass argument to callback function from directive, try to do following changes.

template.html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data"
      ng-click="onItemClick({argItem:item})">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your Main HTML

```
<div my-list="dataArray" on-item-click="showDetailsInModal(argItem)"></div>
```

Here, we need to pass the argument in form of an object and the key of this object will be mapped with the argument of function that is assigned in your template.

Check this working example in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Mt9NZ47UfmJtH3akCLv?p=preview) showing how to pass argument to the function from directive.

Hope this will be useful.